# How do I convert a web page to PDF in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, report

I have a webpage with some data in a table and I would like to offer my users the option to download it as a PDF File, how can I do that in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) library.

Answer (score 1):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) works great and uses the webkit rendering engine (Safari, Chrome) instead of a cooked up html/css parser.

The benefit is that you simply give it your url and it returns a pdf.  You would just need to make a printer friendly version of the page to send to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a report generator like sql report or crystal report to generate the pdf file.
2. You can use third party pdf generate tool , and use it to generate a pdf in memory, and sent it to client use Response.Write.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the MS ReportViewer control and render your PDF from code if you don't want the actual viewer on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net mvc and want to convert result from mvc views into pdf. You can look at this [blog post](http://jsreport.net/blog/rendering-pdf-from-aspnet-mvc-views).

If you are considering to print complex pdf reports from c#. You can check out this [blog post](http://jsreport.net/blog/pdf-reports-in-csharp).

Disclaimer: I am the author of [jsreport](http://jsreport.net).